# web scraping some prices on TSETMC.COM page using cmd prompt, python , scrapy and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, cmd, scrapy

First of all, sorry that the problem statement is being long and I really appreciate your valuable time.
I want to go to the page([www.tsetmc.com](http://www.tsetmc.com/loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=42354736493447489#)). then go to the specified violet tab that is shown in this [image #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUwR2.jpg). finally, sum all of the specified prices that I marked in this [image#2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geH6v.jpg)image.
I write down these codes in the cmd prompt :

```
ipython 
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome('C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\chromedriver')
driver.get('http://tsetmc.com/loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=42354736493447489')
from scrapy.selector import Selector
sel=Selector(text=driver.page_source)
violet_tab=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="violet"]')
violet_tab.click()
html=Selector(text=driver.page_source)
sel=html.xpath('//*[@colspan="2"]//*[@class="ltr inline"]/@title')
sel.extract()
```

the output is these numbers which I want:
[u'2,953,168',
u'5,052,000',
u'5,858,680',
u'-1,220,339',
u'-3,824,076',
u'5,994,542',
u'1,381,622',
u'-7,597,017',
u'-4,909,474',
u'3,471,639',
u'5,135,504',
u'-4,080,390',
u'9,708,055',
u'400,000',
u'6,950,000',
u'284,559',
u'-1,429,175',
u'-400,000',
u'1,400,000',
u'7,269,151',
u'35,234,435',
u'0',
u'-7,495,110',
u'45,933',
u'-2,176,425',
u'1,748,836',
u'0',
u'-10,930,000',
u'-11,600,000',
.........]

**but **the problem is** that I do not know how to write the code in my text editor.**
I try this :

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy import Spider
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from time import sleep

class Khepars444Spider(Spider):
    name = 'khepars444'
    allowed_domains = ['tsetmc.com/loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=42354736493447489']

    def start_requests(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\chromedriver')
        self.driver.get('http://tsetmc.com/loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=42354736493447489')
        sleep(3) # delay 2 sec

        violet_tab=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="violet"]')
        sleep(1)
        self.logger.info('Sleeping for 1 seconds.')
        violet_tab.click()
        html=Selector(text=self.driver.page_source) 
        sel=html.xpath('.//*[@colspan="2"]')
        for taghir in sel :   
            yield Request(taghir.xpath('.//*[@class="ltr inline"]/@title'),callback=self.parse_haghighi)
        

    def parse_haghighi(self,response):
        pass
```

and I get nothing.
I will be happy if you help. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your 2nd code snippet you define your class `Khepars444Spider` but none of its methods is called. The best way would probably to define a `main` function which calls `start_requests`, see https://realpython.com/python-main-function/

Add this snippet to end of your 2nd code, you should then be able to execute the script from the command line.

```
def main():
    spider = Khepars444Spider()
    for request in spider.start_requests():
        print(request)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```